# Using a homography matrix and decomposing it to find the orientation of a plane fixed in the centre

Tags: image, opencv, homography

I currently have two images of a plane in real life from straight above. One to use as a reference image, and another when the plane has undergone a rotation fixed at the centre of the plane thus changing its orientation. The camera stays at a constant position.

I was wondering if I found the homography matrix of this rotation in opencv and then decomposed the homography matrix in order to find the rotation matrix whether this would yield accurate results and I would be able to find the three angles needed to describe the planes rotation in euclidean coordinates to a reasonable degree of accuracy.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean like [decomposeHomographyMat function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga7f60bdff78833d1e3fd6d9d0fd538d92)?

Comment: yes i was just wondering whether that yields in accurate results when used in real life images

Comment: the accuracy depends more on the homography calculation than the decomposition of it

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, am i right in assuming then that if i am just changing the orientation of one plane with easy to detect features fixed at the centre the homography calculation can be accurately done using opencv

Comment: depends on the image, not always is perfect, however if your features are good and numerous you have will get quite accurate results

Comment: i can choose the image myself as i am making something to find the orientation of a plane so hopefully i can choose the features that make it perfect. Thanks for your help